# Cannot center list horizontally

Tags: css

I want to center list inside the div, but cannot. The ol element is centered (takes the whole screen width). But all of the li elements float to the right of the ol (there is some space left on the left side).

```css
#List1 {
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e9400d;
  width: 100%;
}

#List1 ol {
    background-color: blue;
}

#List1 li {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="List1">
  <ol>
    <li>
      Elem1
    </li>
    <li>
      Elem2
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add on this div `display: flex; justify-content: center;`

Answer (score 0):

You want the li's centered? If so, you could take the text-align off the div and change the width percentage of the li's like this...

```
#List1 {
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: #e9400d;
    width: 100%;
}

#List1 li {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: lightskyblue; 
}
```

(it doesn't have to be 80% for the width obviously, you can play with it til you're happy)

Answer (score 0):

This solution should be work :

```css
#List1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9400d;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

#List1 li {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="List1">
  <ol>
    <li>
      Elem1
    </li>
    <li>
      Elem2
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   #List1 ol li 
      {
         display:inline;
      }

   #List1 
      {
        text-align: center; 
      }
   #List1 ol 
      { 
        list-style: none; 
      }
```